You cannot register at this time
When I try to ask a question on judaism.stackexchange.com, I get the following error:

You cannot register at this time.
If you continue to find this error, contact us.
Already have an account? Log in

Now what's strange is (Edit: @zcoop98
commented why this might be happening), that this error occurs at a point when on other sites where I'm not registered I don't have to register yet.  In particular, normally I can at least type in my question, and then I have to register or log in before I can submit it.
Trying this on the Judaism's Meta site does the same thing.  Clicking the "Log in" button brings me to the same page -- it doesn't even ask for my credentials.  Also, the Join this Community button brings me to the same page.  Contacting support also does not work -- clicking the Submit button just brings me back to the page where I have to type my message to support.
It looks like this issue occurred with other people in the past; however, none of the time there was a response which helped the people resolve the issue.

"Contacting support doesn't work". How have you established that? How long have you waited?

Re: "Now what's strange is, that this error occurs at a point when on other sites where I'm not registered I don't have to register yet" - If I recall correctly, some sites don't allow posts by non-logged-in/ unregistered users, and it sounds like Judaism.SE is one of them (I looked for a canonical list here on Meta but couldn't find one?).

@RobertLongson I never get a confirmation saying the report has been submitted -- clicking the Submit button just brings me back to the page where I have to type what I want to submit.

You can go to the /contact page on a different site, e.g. here, and in there explain your problem. Something is off for you on that specific site. Staff might notice this question as well and help, but by submitting a contact form you make sure they see your case.

@ShadowWizard Thank you, submitting this form on another website worked.  Strange that it couldn't even submit this form on judaica.stackexchange.com...

Cheers, and hope it will get resolved soon. :)

Tldr: Use another browser to sign up, and then return to Firefox for everything else.
I followed the advise of @ShadowWizard, and submitted the help ticket through another site where I am already signed up.  The following was the response:

Please try to using a different internet browser and let me know what you get. If you're successful, great! If not, you should see a message that either says, "something went wrong" or an error that contains a RayID. Either way, let me know (and let me know the RayID number if that's what pops up) and I can then look in our logs to see what's causing the issue.

I followed this advice, and opened this site in another browser (Safari).  To my surprise, it automatically signed me up (so I didn't have to click the usual "Join this site" button) -- namely, opening the site was all I had to do, and right away it showed me as signed up.  I refreshed the page in my (up-to-date) Firefox browser, and sure enough, it showed me as having 101 reputation, and the Ask a Question page loaded right away without problems.
